# Does a new watcher see old unhandled events?

Tags: c, libev

If I have a socket and someone sent data to it that I didn't yet handle via `read()`, and now I make an `ev_io` watcher for it and run it, will the callback fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's level-triggered, not edge-triggered, so the callback will fire rapidly until all the pending data was read.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to your question as I've never used `libev`. But I can suggest in the absence of this knowledge you might try to simulate the scenario and see what happens. :-)